# pdflib 8 - text wrap in continue_text or similar function

Tags: c#, .net, pdflib

i'm working with pdflib 8 and adding alot of different strings using the continue_text function. for example:

```
p.continue_text("Title");
p.continue_text("Leadtext");
```

now i need to add some multiline-text, unfortunately i can only specify a fixed-width box for textflows. The textflows need x_startpos and y_startpos, which is unknown after some p.continue_text calls...

so, is there a way to add some wordwrapping to the p.continue_text function (or a similar function)? i've read the manual but didn't find any useful information.